# How to get rid of dynamic SQL (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that uses dynamic SQL. My company recently decided to get rid of dynamic code.

Here I greatly simplified it to explain my point; `@PersonID` and `@MhnNum` are parameters of the stored procedure:

```
Declare @sql Varchar(max)

Set @sql="Select from tableA p"

If @PersonID Is Not Null
    Set @sql = @sql + ' Where  p.[ID] = ' + cast(@PersonID  as varchar(12))      

If @MhnNum Is Not Null
    Set @sql = @sql + ' Where p.[MhnNum] = ' + '''' + cast(@MhnNum  as varchar(12)) + ''''
```

Is there an (easy) way to get rid of this dynamic SQL?

Right now my solution is to create 2 If's with repetitive code. There must be a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure why this needs to be "more elegant" except that you should be using `nvarchar(max)` for `@sql` and passing in strongly-typed parameters to `sys.sp_executesql`. That would be more elegant. Removing the dynamic SQL and using a series of ANDs and ORs might _seem_ more elegant, but it doesn't scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple combination of `or` and `and` can get you the same result:

```
Select *
From tableA
Where (@personId is null or id = @personId) 
And (@MhnNum is null or whnNum =@mhnNum)
```

Comment: Thanks. I accept this as it came in 2 minutes earlier. So If I had more IF's I only needed to add more lines? Where (@personId is null or id = @personId) 
And (@MhnNum is null or whnNum =@mhnNum) AND (@ABC is null or wABC=@ANC) ), ...

Comment: could also do: where IsNull (@personId, id)= id And IsNull(@MhnNum, whnNum) =whnNum @snash

Comment: @SNash If you start adding too many lines, you'll get into a "kitchen sink" scenario where there's no way SQL Server can produce a plan that will be suitable for most combinations. See [this post](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example) for examples.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, Dynamic SQL is probably the way to go, as you have a catch-all query, just not your dynamic SQL. It's a huge injection risk. Parametrise the statements:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
         @CRLF nchar(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);

 SET @SQL = N'SELECT *' + @CRLF +
            N'FROM TableA A' + @CRLF +
            CASE WHEN @PersonID IS NOT NULL THEN N'WHERE A.ID = @PersonID;'
                 WHEN @MhnNum IS NOT NULL THEN N'WHERE A.MhnNum = @MhnNum;'
            END;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@PersonID int, @MhnNum int', @PersonID, @MhnNum;
```

Using a non-dynamic approach will cause the caching of bad query plans, which isn't going to be desired.

If you must use non dynamic SQL (due to a pointless Company Policy, there is nothing wrong with Dynamic SQL if used correctly), then add `OPTION RECOMPILE`:

```
IF @PersonID IS NOT NULL AND @MhnNum IS NOT NULL
    THROW 68542, N'Both @PersonID and @MhnNum cannot be non-NULL values.', 11;

SELECT *
FROM TableA A
WHERE (A.ID = @PersonID OR @PersonID IS NULL)
  AND (A.MhnNum = @MhnNum OR @MhnNum IS NULL)
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

The `THROW` is in there, as your code will also error if you have 2 non-`NULL` values.

Comment: I bet your right, but again I have no choice, it is a company policy.

Comment: I think each condition should be its own `CASE` expression, unless the goal is to only ever support at most one parameter.

Comment: @SNash Could you explain your "company policy"? Can you post it somewhere word for word?

Comment: I agree, @AaronBertrand, but I was kind offollowing the logic to OP had (apart from this doesn't error if they are both not `NULL`)

Comment: If there where many parameters I would probably suggest that as well, but for two parameters only I'm not sure it's worth the hassle... plus if you want to support both of them you have to add extra logic to decide whether to concatenate "where" or "and" before your parameter. Not impossible but getting a little more tricky.  `option(recompile)` makes an easier, more maintainable solution and unless encountering an actual performance problem, that's a better option IMHO.

Comment: @Zohar, I have 2 or at most 3 parameters

Comment: Starting with `WHERE 1 = 1` makes every subsequent predicate an `AND`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

(writing in a comment would be a mess)

You could check the parameters and act accordingly. ie:

```
Select from tableA p
where  (@PersonID IS NULL or p.[ID] = @PersonID) and
 (@MhnNum  IS NULL or p.[MhnNum] = @MhnNum);
```